# How to find out which MySQL query consumes most of CPU time?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I searched lot of topics, but couldn't find any information about how to find which query consumes more CPU time.

I'm using MySQL 8.0 and MySQL Workbench. 
I can find there average and total execution time of queries, but I'm not sure is it an indicator of CPU usage. Queries can take a longer time to execute because of low memory and additional reads from disk.

Comment: You should use [SHOW PROFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-profile.html)   but it is deprecated and will be removed in a future MySQL release.. Or use [Query Profiling Using Performance Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-query-profiling.html) .. If SHOW PROFILE is still working in your DB use it because it's more easy to use..Both should give you a disk I/O indication..

Comment: Otherwise use `EXPLAIN <query>` the worse trouble can start when you use "using temporary; using filesort" in one line this combination uses up the most CPU and disk I/O times (when the temporary table is running on disk)... "using temporary" means the temporary  table is handle by a ram at first but when the data becomes to great it will be converted into a disk based temporary table.. "using filesort" yes filesort is a wierd name because it isn't always a real sort based on a file unless the temporary table is running on disk offcource.

Comment: Thanks guys for help! SHOW PROFILE doesn't work in my DB.

Comment: Raymond, I followed your advice and double checked most time consuming queries with EXPLAIN. They all are quite good optimized, use indexes and don't use temp tables. But I noticed some small optimization which I can still do. Replaced NOW() function in query with PHP calculated date.

Comment: My hardware is 2 x E56XX 2.4GHz CPU, 2Gb RAM, 50Gb SSD, Windows 2008 R2.
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS: https://pastebin.com/pfs1DPzU
thanks for "SHOW GLOBAL STATUS" didn't kknow such command will study it.
Global variables: https://pastebin.com/ESp8ZP6u

Comment: process list: http://prntscr.com/maxp8m
my.ini: https://pastebin.com/9P5mGtSY
This is windowws machine so I don't have MySQLTuner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions to consider for your my.ini [mysqld] section to improve your instance performance,

```
thread_cache_size=100  # from 10 to reduce threads_created count of 34,663 
innodb_flushing_avg_loops=5  # from 30 to reduce loop delay and reduce innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty 1,660 in this STATUS report
max_connections=100  # from 151 to reduce RAM footprint, max_used_connections was 31
innodb_io_capacity=5000  # from 200   stop/start required
if you have innodb_io_capacity_max in your my.ini, REMOVE it for new max of 10000
innodb_open_file=-1  # from 300 for auto calc value = table_open_cache current value of 2000
```

For additional suggestions, view my profile, Network profile for contact info and get in touch by email or Skype, please.

Congratulations on RELEASING RESOURCES with proper use of com_dealloc_sql and com_stmt_close coding technique.

Comment: Thank you very much Wilson! Will check everything you suggested!